# QT duplicate symbol in mainwindow.o and ***.o file

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, tinyxml, duplicate-symbol

I am a little confused, I am trying to develop a simple application.

Application Flow:
MainWindow -> Dialog 1 -> Dialog 2.

MainWindow imports Dialog1.h and Dialog1.h imports Dialog2.h

1) If I import TinyXML Libraries in both Dialog1.cpp and Dialog2.cpp,
the compiler throws following error:
duplicate symbol **RANDOM TINYXML CLASS* in:
    Dialog1.o
    Dialog2.o

2) As Dialog1.h imports Dialog2.h, Even if I try to import TinyXML libraries in only Dialog2.h, I still get following error:
duplicate symbol **RANDOM TINYXML CLASS* in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_Dialog2.o

I am not importing anything in mainwindow. Still the error persists.

Any help on where I am going wrong?

Error Log(There are 732, just copy pasted a bunch):

```
duplicate symbol __ZN11TiXmlString7reserveEm in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN11TiXmlString8nullrep_E in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN11TiXmlString6assignEPKcm in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN11TiXmlString6appendEPKcm in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZplRK11TiXmlStringS1_ in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZplRK11TiXmlStringPKc in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZplPKcRK11TiXmlString in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __Z10TiXmlFOpenPKcS0_ in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlBase12EncodeStringERK11TiXmlStringPS0_ in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlBase6entityE in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNodeC2ENS_8NodeTypeE in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZTV9TiXmlNode in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNodeD2Ev in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNodeD1Ev in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNodeD0Ev in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK9TiXmlNode6CopyToEPS_ in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNode5ClearEv in:
    mainwindow.o
    selectorteach.o

--------------------------------------------------------------------

duplicate symbol __ZNK12TiXmlElement22QueryUnsignedAttributeEPKcPj in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK12TiXmlElement18QueryBoolAttributeEPKcPb in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlBase11StringEqualEPKcS1_b13TiXmlEncoding in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK12TiXmlElement20QueryDoubleAttributeEPKcPd in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZN12TiXmlElement12SetAttributeEPKci in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZN17TiXmlAttributeSet12FindOrCreateEPKc in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZN14TiXmlAttribute11SetIntValueEi in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZN17TiXmlAttributeSet3AddEP14TiXmlAttribute in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZN12TiXmlElement18SetDoubleAttributeEPKcd in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZN14TiXmlAttribute14SetDoubleValueEd in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK12TiXmlElement5PrintEP7__sFILEi in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK12TiXmlElement6AcceptEP12TiXmlVisitor in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK12TiXmlElement5CloneEv in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK12TiXmlElement7GetTextEv in:
    mainwindow.o
    teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZN13TiXmlDocumentC2Ev in:

--------------------------------------------------------------------

duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlBase6entityE in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNodeC2ENS_8NodeTypeE in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZTV9TiXmlNode in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNodeD2Ev in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNodeD1Ev in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNodeD0Ev in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK9TiXmlNode6CopyToEPS_ in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNode5ClearEv in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNode12LinkEndChildEPS_ in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN13TiXmlDocument8SetErrorEiPKcP16TiXmlParsingData13TiXmlEncoding in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK9TiXmlNode11GetDocumentEv in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlBase11errorStringE in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN16TiXmlParsingData5StampEPKc13TiXmlEncoding in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNode14InsertEndChildERKS_ in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNode17InsertBeforeChildEPS_RKS_ in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNode16InsertAfterChildEPS_RKS_ in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_selectorteach.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlNode12ReplaceChildEPS_RKS_ in:

--------------------------------------------------------------------

    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9TiXmlText5ParseEPKcP16TiXmlParsingData13TiXmlEncoding in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZN16TiXmlDeclaration5ParseEPKcP16TiXmlParsingData13TiXmlEncoding in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTV12TiXmlPrinter in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTV14TiXmlAttribute in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTV12TiXmlUnknown in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTV9TiXmlText in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZN11TiXmlString4nposE in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTI9TiXmlNode in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTI12TiXmlElement in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTI13TiXmlDocument in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTI12TiXmlComment in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTI16TiXmlDeclaration in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTI14TiXmlAttribute in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTS14TiXmlAttribute in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTS9TiXmlNode in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTS12TiXmlComment in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTI9TiXmlText in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTS9TiXmlText in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTS16TiXmlDeclaration in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTI12TiXmlUnknown in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTS12TiXmlUnknown in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTS13TiXmlDocument in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTI12TiXmlPrinter in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTS12TiXmlPrinter in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
duplicate symbol __ZTS12TiXmlElement in:
    mainwindow.o
    moc_teachmode.o
ld: 732 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [untitled.app/Contents/MacOS/untitled] Error 1
19:03:15: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Note: When I include the files in only Dialog2.cpp, the project compiles and all functions work as expected. The problem only occurs when I place it in the header file.
My include directives for TinyXML:-

```
   #include <tinystr.h>
   #include <tinyxml.h>
   #include <tinystr.cpp>
   #include <tinyxmlerror.cpp
   #include <tinyxml.cpp>
   #include <tinyxmlparser.cpp>
```

If I only include the source files such as:

```
#include <tinystr.h>
#include <tinyxml.h>
```

I get the following error log:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "TiXmlString::assign(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      TiXmlString::operator=(char const*) in teachmode.o
  "TiXmlString::nullrep_", referenced from:
      TiXmlString::quit() in teachmode.o
  "TiXmlElement::SetAttribute(char const*, char const*)", referenced from:
      saveData(product) in teachmode.o
  "TiXmlElement::SetAttribute(char const*, int)", referenced from:
      saveData(product) in teachmode.o
  "TiXmlElement::TiXmlElement(char const*)", referenced from:
      saveData(product) in teachmode.o
  "TiXmlDocument::LoadFile(char const*, TiXmlEncoding)", referenced from:
      saveData(product) in teachmode.o
  "TiXmlDocument::TiXmlDocument()", referenced from:
      saveData(product) in teachmode.o
  "TiXmlDeclaration::TiXmlDeclaration(char const*, char const*, char const*)", referenced from:
      saveData(product) in teachmode.o
  "TiXmlNode::LinkEndChild(TiXmlNode*)", referenced from:
      saveData(product) in teachmode.o
  "TiXmlNode::TiXmlNode(TiXmlNode::NodeType)", referenced from:
      TiXmlText::TiXmlText(char const*) in teachmode.o
  "TiXmlNode::~TiXmlNode()", referenced from:
      TiXmlDocument::~TiXmlDocument() in teachmode.o
      TiXmlText::TiXmlText(char const*) in teachmode.o
  "TiXmlDocument::SaveFile(char const*) const", referenced from:
      saveData(product) in teachmode.o
  "TiXmlNode::FirstChildElement() const", referenced from:
      TiXmlNode::FirstChildElement() in teachmode.o
  "vtable for TiXmlDocument", referenced from:
      TiXmlDocument::~TiXmlDocument() in teachmode.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for TiXmlText", referenced from:
      TiXmlText::TiXmlText(char const*) in teachmode.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [untitled.app/Contents/MacOS/untitled] Error 1
19:25:51: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Comment: Are you sure the symbol is really *random*? When you get a duplicate symbol or multiple definition linker error, it usually means you *defined* the symbol in a header file, and included that header file in multiple source files. Header files should rarely *define* symbols, only *declare* them. More specific than that is impossible to get without seeing any source or actual error output.

Comment: Are you maybe including your own class multiple times by accident? Are you using [include guards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483955/c-include-guard) in all of your classes?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  Updated the question with actual error output, The randomness is just various class names.  I have used project search to ensure that no repetition exists.

Comment: @Bowdzone I am using project search to ensure that include statements have only been written once. Updated the question with error output.

Comment: Are you including the TinyXML *source* file or the *header* file? Please show some code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: Why are you including `cpp` files? I've never seen a library where this would be necessary

Comment: @Bowdzone I had tried not including them, but including them makes it compile correctly. I have updated the error log that occurs when they arent included. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include the *source files*, that's what's causing your problem!

Include only the header-files, and then compile and link the source files as you do with your own source files.

---

The source file contains the *definitions* of all functions, and you can only have a single definition in your program.

Comment: Hello! I have tried not including them but they also give Undefined symbols, I have updated the error log in the question for that also. Please check, Thank you!

Comment: @AakashThakkar That's because you need to *build with those source files too*. You have, as I understand it, two source files in your project. Just add the TinyXML source files to your project so those will be built and linked with your code.