# Calling C++ code from iOS Swift: duplicate symbol error

Tags: c++, ios, swift, objective-c

In my iOS project, I want to call C++ code from my Swift code.

So, following [this tutorial](https://anuragajwani.medium.com/how-to-consume-c-code-in-swift-b4d64a04e989) and adding a little bit more stuff, here is what I did:

- I create the `NativeLibWrapper.h` file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NativeLibWrapper : NSObject

- (NSString *) sayHello: (bool) boolTest;

@end
```

- I create the `NativeLibWrapper.mm` file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "NativeLibWrapper.h"
#import "NativeLib.cpp"

@implementation NativeLibWrapper

- (NSString *) sayHello: (bool) boolTest {
    NativeLib nativeLib;
    std::string retour = nativeLib.sayHello(boolTest);
    return [NSString stringWithCString: retour.c_str() encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

@end
```

- I create the `NativeLib.hpp` file:

```
#ifndef NativeLib_hpp
#define NativeLib_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

class NativeLib
{
public:
    std::string sayHello(bool boolTest);
};

#endif /* NativeLib_hpp */
```

- I create the `NativeLib.cpp` file:

```
#include "NativeLib.hpp"

std::string NativeLib::sayHello(bool boolTest)
{
    return "Hello C++ : " + std::to_string(boolTest);
}
```

- I add the following in `Runner/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h`:

```
#import "NativeLibWrapper.h"
```

- And finally, I call the C++ function in Swift:

```
NativeLibWrapper().sayHello(true)
```

But if I compile that code, I have the following error:

```
duplicate symbol 'NativeLib::sayHello(bool)' in:
        /Users/mreg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-behadtvychvlasailnoaimvxgbwa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/NativeLib.o
        /Users/mreg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-behadtvychvlasailnoaimvxgbwa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/NativeLibWrapper.o
    ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
```

After some research, I found out that, if I change the `NativeLib.cpp` content with:

```
#include "NativeLib.hpp"

std::string NativeLib::sayHello(bool boolTest)
{
    return "Hello C++"; // + std::to_string(boolTest);
}
```

now, it compiles and works, which is... weird.

So what can I do to get rid of this error, while keeping the original content of `NativeLib.cpp`?

Thanks.

Comment: NativeLibWrapper.mm should import "NativeLib.hpp", not "NativeLib.cpp"

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/28345794/1187415

Comment: Thanks all, that was the right answer! You can post the answer so I will accept it, if you want ;)

Comment: Btw, it is correctly described in the tutorial.

Comment: Well, it seems that this has been asked and answered several times already, here is another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52062179/1187415. My suggestion would be to close this as a duplicate or delete the question.